# How to findByIdAndUpdate() without deleting existing data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a mongoose Person model that looks like this:

```
const PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: {
        street: String,
        number: number
    }
});
```

Then I have a method for updating people's info, like this:

```
const updatePerson = async (req, res) => {
    const updatedPerson = await Person.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, { new: true });
    return updatedPerson;
}
```

So far, so good. Now let's say I have this record in my database:

```
{
    "_id": "5ed2918bc96be94f130e1354",
    "name": "Freddy",
    "address": {
         "street": "Elm Street",
         "number": 42
    }
}
```

And I want to update the name and the street, so I send this request:

```
{ "name": "Ryu", "address": { "street": "fighter" } }
```

My document will become like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5ed2918bc96be94f130e1354",
    "name": "Ryu",
    "address": { "street": "fighter" }
}
```

In other words, the "number" property was deleted from the record. Since I didn't provide a value for "number" in my request, the original one was overwritten by undefined. Is there any way I can preserve existing data with the `.findByIdAndUpdate()` method?

I know you can do this with `.findById()`, updating what you need "manually" and then calling `.save()`, but I guess it would be more elegant if you could pass some option to `.findByIdAndUpdate()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Person.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$set: 
{'fieldtoupdate1':newvalue1,'fieldtoupdate2':newvalue2}}).exec()
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution to your problem is to update the object's property directly by setting its value and not setting the object to a new object.

Old:

```
{ "name": "Ryu", "address": { "street": "fighter" } }
```

New:

```
{ "name": "Ryu", "address.street": "fighter" }
```